# Date time still thinking its null even though I have set its nullable value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create a entity object but I am having some issues regarding my dates it claims it doesnt have a value even though I have set the blank date to 1900.

```
DateTime startDate = rdStarDate.SelectedDate.Value == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) ? DateTime.Today : rdStarDate.SelectedDate.Value;
```

Below is the save function in which its being used.

```
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);


    _appointment = _dal.GetAppointMentByiD(id ,"");

    _appointment.CustomName = txtCustomerName.Text;
    DateTime startDate = rdStarDate.SelectedDate.Value == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) ? DateTime.Today : rdStarDate.SelectedDate.Value;

    DateTime endDate = rdEndDate.SelectedDate.Value == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) ? DateTime.Today : rdEndDate.SelectedDate.Value;

    _appointment.Start = startDate;
    _appointment.End = endDate;
    _appointment.Subject = txtSubject.Text;

    _appointment.notes = txtNotes.Text;
    _appointment.preferedContactNumber = txtContactNum.Text;
    _appointment.mobileNumber = txtMobileNumber.Text;
    _appointment.authUserName = Environment.UserName;
    _appointment.authCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        if (id == 0)
        {
            _dal.AddApointments(_appointment);
        }
    _dal.SaveChanges();
    rdMessaeBox.RadAlert("Appointment Saved", 200, 100, "Calander", "callBackFn", "myAlertImage.png");
  Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
```

> Error in .net is
>      Nullable object must have a value.
>      Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the  current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
```

Comment: If `rdStarDate.SelectedDate == null` , then accessing `.Value` will throw that exception. If that's not the case, explain where exactly the exception occurs.

Comment: Yes it is that  what is best way then to use that value is their like a tryParse for date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime startDate = rdStarDate.SelectedDate.Value == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) ? DateTime.Today : rdStarDate.SelectedDate.Value;
```

This line says: *when* `rdStartDate.SelectedDate.Value` is exactly `1900/1/1`, then (and only then) set `startDate` to `DateTime.Today`.
If it is `null`, accessing `rdStartDate.SelectedDate.Value` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` with the exact message you received!

I think what you actually wanted is

```
DateTime startDate = (!rdStarDate.SelectedDate.HasValue ||
    rdStarDate.SelectedDate.Value == new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)) 
    ? DateTime.Today 
    : rdStarDate.SelectedDate.Value;
```

---

You stated that you *did* set `rdStarTime.SelectedValue` to `1900/1/1`, but you did not show that line, nor did you show the stack trace of the exception. So if you *really* set that value, the only other possibility where the exception could be raised is the same line for your `rdEndDate.SelectedValue.Value`.

*P.S.: Shouldn't it be `rdStartDate` instead of `rdStarDate`?*